# WooCommerce do action on checkout field input

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this field at woocommerce checkout:

```
<input type="text" class="input-text wfacp-form-control" name="zipcode" id="zipcode" placeholder="" value="">
```

I am trying to fire action, when this field is changed.
Code i tried is this:

```
add_action('wp_head', function() {
    if ( is_checkout ) {

        ?><script>
           
     jQuery('input#zipcode').change(function() { 
          alert('Changed!')
     });
    
        </script><?php
    }
});
```

Unfortunatelly it's not working. Can someone tip me to the right direction?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest flaw in your code is that `is_checkout` should be `is_checkout()`. Also the way you apply jQuery is wrong

So you get:

```php
// jQuery code
function action_wp_head() {
    if ( is_checkout() ) {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        // Selector
        $( 'input#zipcode' ).change(function() {
            alert( 'Changed!' );
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'action_wp_head' );
```